# How to render Bootstrap admin template?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, templates, django-templates

I have this [admin panel template](https://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/pooled-admin-panel-category-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/) and I want to use it in my Django web application. I know I will have to modify the template using template tags but is that all? What all changes will I have to make. I am fairly new to Django and front end development.

Comment: Change the references like this `<link href="../files/style.css">` to something like this `<link href="{% static 'path/to/css/file' %}>`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be so kind and add any relevant code you have by editing the question, so we can help you fix the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty easy, indeed to work with Django and front-end. Answering your question: Yes, you have to change some more things to the template. You have to change links to something like

```html
<link href="{% static 'templates/my_app/css/style.css' %}>
```

Also, you have to be quite careful with the views and Models python files. The views will determine what will your administrative system will do, using the models.